# ubuntu 18.04 having problems with wifi and bluetooth

Tags: wireless, 18.04, bluetooth, iwlwifi, ubuntu-drivers

On my laptop Dell Vostro 14 3445, I am facing problem to start wifi and Bluetooth.

I don't think that that is a hardware issue in my laptop as it would work with the windows OS before I switch to Ubuntu 18.04. I have tried ample solution given on net to fix this but ultimately I think I have to raise this specific to my machine. Not sure how my machine is different than others where they were able to fix their boxes.

Linux header version is linux-headers-4.15.0-42

These are few informations about my system components:

```
$lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; rfkill list; uname -r; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:0682]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
Kernel modules: bcma
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 064e:9205 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:108a Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
4.15.0-42-generic
[    0.064453] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.396427] [drm] Found UVD firmware Version: 1.64 Family ID: 9
[    2.398434] [drm] Found VCE firmware/feedback version 40.2.2 / 15!
[   24.332467] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   24.332506] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   24.332512] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   24.332515] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   24.332524] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   70.312690] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   70.312694] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   70.312704] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Please help, Thanks in advance.

```
$ dkms status
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.15.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
btusb, 4.0, 4.15.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**Solution**

I found my answer. I have looked many posts to fix this.

I tried did this:

```
enabled wifi adapter from Software & updates -> additional Drivers -> [select the dirver] -> Click on 'Apply changes'
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Then:

```
disabled `secure boot` from `bios`
```

then:

```
Reboot the system.
```

And i see this stuff working

Comment: I found my answer. I have looked many posts to fix this.

I tried did this: 

enabled wifi adapter from Software & updates -> additional Drivers -> [select the dirver] -> Click on 'Apply changes'
then:
    `sudo apt-get update`
    `sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source`
Then
disabled `secure boot` from `bios`

then:
Reboot the system. 
and i see this stuff working

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer. I have looked many posts to fix this. I tried did this: enabled wifi adapter from Software & updates -> additional Drivers -> [select the dirver] -> Click on 'Apply changes' then: sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source Then disabled secure boot from bios then: Reboot the system. and i see this stuff working